# Hide the status bar in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, web

I would like to hide the status bar in Firefox when the mouse is over a link. Here is what the status bar is :
http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/what-happened-status-bar

I already tried window.status with javascript but it doesn't work even if I set dom.disable_window_status_change to false. I didn't find any add-ons ever.

Does someone have a solution ?

NB : this is only for a web application which won't be published on the Internet, my goal is not to hide a target link :)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This won't be possible / allowed by the browser for security reasons.

If this is an absolute requirement, is specific to Firefox, and you control the web browsers for the users that will be using this application, you could write your own Firefox extension to do this for your specific site.

Answer (score 2):

This will not work because this is built in for safety reasons.
To prevent phishing for example or other bad things you can do.
I mean I'm not sure but what you could do is leave the `a href =""` tag attribute empty or just insert `href="#"` and add some javascript which redirects the user to the page you want when he clicks that link. But I'm really not sure if this would work in the way you want it !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. We're using this solution at the moment and if there is no way to hide the status bar we'll stick with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can't hide it when it is over a link, but one way to get around it would be to attach click events to `span` elements that change the window location. So they would act like links, but there wouldn't be a `href` attribute to show in the status.

Comment: I like you're idea and it might be better than a javascript redirection, I'll let you know.